# Make all Infopath 2013 error messages easier to locate than the default

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, sharepoint-server

In an existing InfoPath 2013 form that I am working with, there are edits in the custom form that uses a custom list. Which is ok. The problem is it is hard to find all the errors if there are a lot of errors.

What I would like to do is have an error message display in red under every column where errors are located after the user hits the submit button.

Basically I would like to have some way of allowing the users to find all there error messages a lot easier after they hit the submit button.

Thus can you tell me if the above request is possible? If so can you tell me and/or point me to links that will have all the error message(s) easier for the user to find after they enter data in a column or they hit have save button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add rules to validate each field and display an error message if it fails.

Adding validation rules to controls in a form template ensures that the data collected is accurate and consistent. When you add a text control, users can type anything into it. However, if you want to restrict users to entering an email address, then use a validation rule that ensures that what a user enters into the field matches the pattern of an email address, and prompt them to correct it if it is not.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-rules-for-validation-fa530b5c-419f-4c03-a85f-d7f96cb9de95?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US